# onActivityResult not called

Tags: java, android, android-intent

There are many question here from people having the exact same problem as I, and I've looked though a million, tried different things for 2-3 hours now, and I still can't get it working.

Child Activity:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(myColorPicker.this, WidgetConfig.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("key", appwidget_notecolor);
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

Parent Activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  // Toast does not show
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onActivityResult fired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
        // Toast does not show
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result Recieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I launch child activity from parent activity like this:

```
Intent myColorPickerIntent = new Intent(WidgetConfig.this, myColorPicker.class);
myColorPickerIntent.putExtra("appwidget_notecolor", appwidget_notecolor);
WidgetConfig.this.startActivity(myColorPickerIntent);
```

Comment: Did you use `startActivityForResult()` or `startActivity()` for launching the child activity?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad that was the problem, replacing startActivity() with startActivityForResult(), did fix it. Thank you

Comment: Good details for using `startActivityForResult()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/2162226

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course you won't get the result, you're calling startActivity() instead of startActivityForResult().

Comment: Thanks! that was it, I'll accept your answer when it allows me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You don't seem to be calling startActivityForResult() after creating the Intent.

Answer (score 3):

Are you pass the intent to startActivityForResult() method?